# How to add custom XAML attributes to a class that inherits UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom UserControl and I want to give it a custom property `"MyProperty"` which I can set in XAML.  So that my XAML will look like this:

```
<EventDet:EventAddressControl 
            MyCustomProperty="formattype"     
            x:Name="EventSessionLocationControl"/>
```

How do I give the UserControl a custom attribute / property which I can then set in XAML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using CLRProperty you cannot use for Binding purpose.

```
 public partial class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{
    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string MyCLRProperty { get; set; }

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomControl ));
}
```

```
 <my:MyCustomControl MyProperty="{Binding BindingProperty}"
                     MyCLRProperty="MyCLRProperty"/>
```

Comment: Not entirely true, depends on what modes you are using and what you are using as the source/target.

Answer (score 2):

Just put a normal [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) in your class.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set the value from xaml then you can use a regular property. If you want to use the property with triggers, styles, etc then you would need to use a dependency property to take advantage of those WPF features